MySQL deadlock when using SELECT FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED?
I have a queue system built using PHP and MySQL (I initially built it using redis, but it was kinda complicated and not very flexible), and after doing some research I found out that since MySQL 8.0.1, there is a new argument that made it possible to (efficiently? and reliably?) build queues with MySQL, and that new argument is FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED, which from what I read, should prevent deadlocks, some references ref 1, ref 2, ref 3.
In my current implementation I have two tables, called QueueJobsPending nad QueueJobsProcessed, as their names suggest, the first one holds only pending jobs and the other one hold the processed ones (both failed and successful), the tables are as follows.
CREATE TABLE QueueJobsPending (
    id CHAR(15) BINARY UNIQUE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id),
    jobKey VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    jobState ENUM('Pending', 'Processing') NOT NULL,
    queueName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    params JSON NOT NULL,
    tags JSON NOT NULL,
    maxExecutionTime INTEGER NOT NULL,
    maxReleases INTEGER NOT NULL,
    releasesCounter INTEGER NOT NULL,
    maxRetries INTEGER NOT NULL,
    retriesCounter INTEGER NOT NULL,
    executeAfterTimestamp INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    createdAt TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    updatedAt TIMESTAMP NULL,
    sequence BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, KEY sequence (sequence)
);

CREATE INDEX index_jobKey ON QueueJobsPending(jobKey);
CREATE INDEX index_jobState ON QueueJobsPending(jobState);
CREATE INDEX index_queueName ON QueueJobsPending(queueName);
CREATE INDEX index_executeAfterTimestamp ON QueueJobsPending(executeAfterTimestamp);

CREATE TABLE QueueJobsProcessed (
    id CHAR(15) BINARY UNIQUE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id),
    pendingQueueJobId CHAR(15) BINARY UNIQUE NOT NULL, -- ONLY FOR THE PURPOSES OF ENSURING A PENDING JOB IS NOT PROCESSED TWICE
    jobKey VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    jobState ENUM('Completed','Failed') NOT NULL,
    queueName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    params JSON NOT NULL,
    tags JSON NOT NULL,
    errors JSON NOT NULL,
    maxExecutionTime INTEGER NOT NULL,
    maxReleases INTEGER NOT NULL,
    releasesCounter INTEGER NOT NULL,
    maxRetries INTEGER NOT NULL,
    retriesCounter INTEGER NOT NULL,
    executeAfterTimestamp INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    createdAt TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    sequence BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, KEY sequence (sequence)
);

CREATE INDEX index_jobKey ON QueueJobsProcessed(jobKey);
CREATE INDEX index_jobState ON QueueJobsProcessed(jobState);
CREATE INDEX index_queueName ON QueueJobsProcessed(queueName);

And when retrieving the next job to be processed I run the following two queries inside a transaction.
SELECT *
FROM QueueJobsPending
WHERE
    jobState = 'Pending'
    AND executeAfterTimestamp <= 123456789
    AND queueName IN ('High','Medium','Low')
ORDER BY FIELD(queueName, 'High','Medium','Low'), sequence ASC
LIMIT 1
FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;

If there is a pending job, then I immediately update its state to 'Pending' with the followinf query.
UPDATE QueueJobsPending
SET jobKey = 'SendCompanyUserAppointmentRescheduledEmail',jobState = 'Processing',queueName = 'Medium',params = '{\"orderId\":\"jNpAhJ9oOLqJkjv\"}',tags = '{\"orderId\":\"jNpAhJ9oOLqJkjv\",\"companyId\":\"87ZIKFuNgI14YSW\"}',maxExecutionTime = '30',maxReleases = '0',releasesCounter = '0',maxRetries = '3',retriesCounter = '0',executeAfterTimestamp = '1733005138',createdAt = '2024-11-30 22:18:58',updatedAt = '2024-11-30 22:18:59'
WHERE id = 'K4cr7SCAaIQDsxl'

Note: I update the status to Processing, before actually processing the job, to make these two queries run as close to each other as possible and to prevent other workers from picking up the same job (which obviously is not always happening as expected, otherwise I wouldn't be here )
And finally commit the transaction.
Here is the exact PHP code from my repository that fetches the next job to be processed.
// PendingQueueJobRepositoryMySQL.php

public function getNextJob(array $queueNames): ?PendingQueueJob
{
    if (empty($queueNames)) {
        throw new QueueException('Queue name list should not be empty.');
    }

    $pendingQueueJobColumns = $this->pendingQueueJobHydrator->getTableColumnsForSelect();
    $now = $this->clock->now(TimeZoneEnum::UTC)->toTimestamp();

    $queueNames = array_map(fn (string $queueName) => $this->quote($queueName), $queueNames);
    $queueNamesStr = implode(',', $queueNames);

    $pendingStateStr = PendingQueueJobStateEnum::Pending->value;

    try {
        $this->beginTransaction();

        $query = "
            SELECT {$pendingQueueJobColumns}
            FROM QueueJobsPending
            WHERE
                jobState = '{$pendingStateStr}'
                AND executeAfterTimestamp <= '{$now}'
                AND queueName IN ({$queueNamesStr})
            ORDER BY FIELD(queueName, {$queueNamesStr}), sequence ASC
            LIMIT 1
            FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
        ";

        $record = $this->fetchSingle($query);
        $job = null;

        if ($record) {
            $job = $this->pendingQueueJobHydrator->single($record);
            $job = $job->setProcessing();

            $this->update($job);
        }

        $this->commitTransaction();

        return $job;
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        $this->rollbackTransaction();

        throw $th;
    }
}

// PendingQueueJob.php file

public function setProcessing(): self
{
    return new self(
        // Update
        jobState: PendingQueueJobStateEnum::Processing,
        updatedAt: AppDateTime::now(),
        //Same
        id: $this->id,
        jobKey: $this->jobKey,
        queueName: $this->queueName,
        params: $this->params,
        tags: $this->tags,
        maxExecutionTime: $this->maxExecutionTime,
        maxReleases: $this->maxReleases,
        releasesCounter: $this->releasesCounter,
        maxRetries: $this->maxRetries,
        retriesCounter: $this->retriesCounter,
        executeAfterTimestamp: $this->executeAfterTimestamp,
        createdAt: $this->createdAt,
    );
}

// PendingQueueJobRepositoryMySQL.php

public function update(PendingQueueJob $entity): void
{
    $columnsForUpdate = $this->pendingQueueJobHydrator->getTableColumnsForUpdate();

    $query = "
        UPDATE QueueJobsPending
        SET {$columnsForUpdate}
        WHERE id = :id;
    ";

    $data = $this->pendingQueueJobHydrator->serialize($entity);

    $this->execute($query, $data);
}


If an instance is returned from getNextJob (which by now should have been set as Processing) the worker will then process it and once finished will hard delete it from the QueueJobPending table and move it to the QueueJobsProcessed one.
But after testing my app I noticed that I was getting deadlock exceptions like this one (this logging style is only used locally for development).
Array
(
    [loggedAt] => 2024-11-30 22:18:59.563000
    [content] => Array
        (
            [exception] => App\Support\Infrastructure\Exception\DatabaseException
            [message] => SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
            [file] => /var/www/app/backend/App/Support/Infrastructure/Database/Repository/AbstractPDORepository.php
            [line] => 116
            [context] => Array
                (
                    [params] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => K4cr7SCAaIQDsxl
                            [jobKey] => SendCompanyUserAppointmentRescheduledEmail
                            [jobState] => Processing
                            [queueName] => Medium
                            [params] => {"orderId":"jNpAhJ9oOLqJkjv"}
                            [tags] => {"orderId":"jNpAhJ9oOLqJkjv","companyId":"87ZIKFuNgI14YSW"}
                            [maxExecutionTime] => 30
                            [maxReleases] => 0
                            [releasesCounter] => 0
                            [maxRetries] => 3
                            [retriesCounter] => 0
                            [executeAfterTimestamp] => 1733005138
                            [createdAt] => 2024-11-30 22:18:58
                            [updatedAt] => 2024-11-30 22:18:59
                        )

                    [query] => 
            UPDATE QueueJobsPending
            SET jobKey = :jobKey,jobState = :jobState,queueName = :queueName,params = :params,tags = :tags,maxExecutionTime = :maxExecutionTime,maxReleases = :maxReleases,releasesCounter = :releasesCounter,maxRetries = :maxRetries,retriesCounter = :retriesCounter,executeAfterTimestamp = :executeAfterTimestamp,createdAt = :createdAt,updatedAt = :updatedAt
            WHERE id = :id;
        
                )
        )

    [stackTrace] => Array
        (
            [0] => disabled
        )

)

And here is the relevant logs from MySQL regarding that specific deadlock (I believe).
Please search for the string K4cr7SCAaIQDsxl, which is the entity ID related to the deadlock, you will see there are two update statements targeting that ID, one succedded but the other one was rolled back, towards the end.
2024-11-30T22:18:59.521235Z    15 Execute   SELECT QueueJobsPending.id AS QueueJobsPending_id,QueueJobsPending.jobKey AS QueueJobsPending_jobKey,QueueJobsPending.jobState AS QueueJobsPending_jobState,QueueJobsPending.queueName AS QueueJobsPending_queueName,QueueJobsPending.params AS QueueJobsPending_params,QueueJobsPending.tags AS QueueJobsPending_tags,QueueJobsPending.maxExecutionTime AS QueueJobsPending_maxExecutionTime,QueueJobsPending.maxReleases AS QueueJobsPending_maxReleases,QueueJobsPending.releasesCounter AS QueueJobsPending_releasesCounter,QueueJobsPending.maxRetries AS QueueJobsPending_maxRetries,QueueJobsPending.retriesCounter AS QueueJobsPending_retriesCounter,QueueJobsPending.executeAfterTimestamp AS QueueJobsPending_executeAfterTimestamp,QueueJobsPending.createdAt AS QueueJobsPending_createdAt,QueueJobsPending.updatedAt AS QueueJobsPending_updatedAt
                FROM QueueJobsPending
                WHERE
                    jobState = 'Pending'
                    AND executeAfterTimestamp <= '1733005139'
                    AND queueName IN ('low','high','medium')
                ORDER BY FIELD(queueName, 'low','high','medium'), sequence ASC
                LIMIT 1
                FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
2024-11-30T22:18:59.521267Z    21 Prepare   SELECT QueueJobsPending.id AS QueueJobsPending_id,QueueJobsPending.jobKey AS QueueJobsPending_jobKey,QueueJobsPending.jobState AS QueueJobsPending_jobState,QueueJobsPending.queueName AS QueueJobsPending_queueName,QueueJobsPending.params AS QueueJobsPending_params,QueueJobsPending.tags AS QueueJobsPending_tags,QueueJobsPending.maxExecutionTime AS QueueJobsPending_maxExecutionTime,QueueJobsPending.maxReleases AS QueueJobsPending_maxReleases,QueueJobsPending.releasesCounter AS QueueJobsPending_releasesCounter,QueueJobsPending.maxRetries AS QueueJobsPending_maxRetries,QueueJobsPending.retriesCounter AS QueueJobsPending_retriesCounter,QueueJobsPending.executeAfterTimestamp AS QueueJobsPending_executeAfterTimestamp,QueueJobsPending.createdAt AS QueueJobsPending_createdAt,QueueJobsPending.updatedAt AS QueueJobsPending_updatedAt
                FROM QueueJobsPending
                WHERE
                    jobState = 'Pending'
                    AND executeAfterTimestamp <= '1733005139'
                    AND queueName IN ('medium','high','low')
                ORDER BY FIELD(queueName, 'medium','high','low'), sequence ASC
                LIMIT 1
                FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
2024-11-30T22:18:59.522084Z    21 Execute   SELECT QueueJobsPending.id AS QueueJobsPending_id,QueueJobsPending.jobKey AS QueueJobsPending_jobKey,QueueJobsPending.jobState AS QueueJobsPending_jobState,QueueJobsPending.queueName AS QueueJobsPending_queueName,QueueJobsPending.params AS QueueJobsPending_params,QueueJobsPending.tags AS QueueJobsPending_tags,QueueJobsPending.maxExecutionTime AS QueueJobsPending_maxExecutionTime,QueueJobsPending.maxReleases AS QueueJobsPending_maxReleases,QueueJobsPending.releasesCounter AS QueueJobsPending_releasesCounter,QueueJobsPending.maxRetries AS QueueJobsPending_maxRetries,QueueJobsPending.retriesCounter AS QueueJobsPending_retriesCounter,QueueJobsPending.executeAfterTimestamp AS QueueJobsPending_executeAfterTimestamp,QueueJobsPending.createdAt AS QueueJobsPending_createdAt,QueueJobsPending.updatedAt AS QueueJobsPending_updatedAt
                FROM QueueJobsPending
                WHERE
                    jobState = 'Pending'
                    AND executeAfterTimestamp <= '1733005139'
                    AND queueName IN ('medium','high','low')
                ORDER BY FIELD(queueName, 'medium','high','low'), sequence ASC
                LIMIT 1
                FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED

...
...
...
...

2024-11-30T22:18:59.530642Z    12 Execute   SELECT QueueJobsPending.id AS QueueJobsPending_id,QueueJobsPending.jobKey AS QueueJobsPending_jobKey,QueueJobsPending.jobState AS QueueJobsPending_jobState,QueueJobsPending.queueName AS QueueJobsPending_queueName,QueueJobsPending.params AS QueueJobsPending_params,QueueJobsPending.tags AS QueueJobsPending_tags,QueueJobsPending.maxExecutionTime AS QueueJobsPending_maxExecutionTime,QueueJobsPending.maxReleases AS QueueJobsPending_maxReleases,QueueJobsPending.releasesCounter AS QueueJobsPending_releasesCounter,QueueJobsPending.maxRetries AS QueueJobsPending_maxRetries,QueueJobsPending.retriesCounter AS QueueJobsPending_retriesCounter,QueueJobsPending.executeAfterTimestamp AS QueueJobsPending_executeAfterTimestamp,QueueJobsPending.createdAt AS QueueJobsPending_createdAt,QueueJobsPending.updatedAt AS QueueJobsPending_updatedAt
                FROM QueueJobsPending
                WHERE
                    jobState = 'Pending'
                    AND executeAfterTimestamp <= '1733005139'
                    AND queueName IN ('high','medium','low')
                ORDER BY FIELD(queueName, 'high','medium','low'), sequence ASC
                LIMIT 1
                FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
2024-11-30T22:18:59.531114Z    12 Close stmt    
2024-11-30T22:18:59.531218Z    12 Query COMMIT
2024-11-30T22:18:59.531533Z    21 Close stmt    
2024-11-30T22:18:59.531854Z    17 Prepare   SELECT QueueJobsPending.id AS QueueJobsPending_id,QueueJobsPending.jobKey AS QueueJobsPending_jobKey,QueueJobsPending.jobState AS QueueJobsPending_jobState,QueueJobsPending.queueName AS QueueJobsPending_queueName,QueueJobsPending.params AS QueueJobsPending_params,QueueJobsPending.tags AS QueueJobsPending_tags,QueueJobsPending.maxExecutionTime AS QueueJobsPending_maxExecutionTime,QueueJobsPending.maxReleases AS QueueJobsPending_maxReleases,QueueJobsPending.releasesCounter AS QueueJobsPending_releasesCounter,QueueJobsPending.maxRetries AS QueueJobsPending_maxRetries,QueueJobsPending.retriesCounter AS QueueJobsPending_retriesCounter,QueueJobsPending.executeAfterTimestamp AS QueueJobsPending_executeAfterTimestamp,QueueJobsPending.createdAt AS QueueJobsPending_createdAt,QueueJobsPending.updatedAt AS QueueJobsPending_updatedAt
                FROM QueueJobsPending
                WHERE
                    jobState = 'Pending'
                    AND executeAfterTimestamp <= '1733005139'
                    AND queueName IN ('low','high','medium')
                ORDER BY FIELD(queueName, 'low','high','medium'), sequence ASC
                LIMIT 1
                FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
2024-11-30T22:18:59.531918Z    17 Execute   SELECT QueueJobsPending.id AS QueueJobsPending_id,QueueJobsPending.jobKey AS QueueJobsPending_jobKey,QueueJobsPending.jobState AS QueueJobsPending_jobState,QueueJobsPending.queueName AS QueueJobsPending_queueName,QueueJobsPending.params AS QueueJobsPending_params,QueueJobsPending.tags AS QueueJobsPending_tags,QueueJobsPending.maxExecutionTime AS QueueJobsPending_maxExecutionTime,QueueJobsPending.maxReleases AS QueueJobsPending_maxReleases,QueueJobsPending.releasesCounter AS QueueJobsPending_releasesCounter,QueueJobsPending.maxRetries AS QueueJobsPending_maxRetries,QueueJobsPending.retriesCounter AS QueueJobsPending_retriesCounter,QueueJobsPending.executeAfterTimestamp AS QueueJobsPending_executeAfterTimestamp,QueueJobsPending.createdAt AS QueueJobsPending_createdAt,QueueJobsPending.updatedAt AS QueueJobsPending_updatedAt
                FROM QueueJobsPending
                WHERE
                    jobState = 'Pending'
                    AND executeAfterTimestamp <= '1733005139'
                    AND queueName IN ('low','high','medium')
                ORDER BY FIELD(queueName, 'low','high','medium'), sequence ASC
                LIMIT 1
                FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
2024-11-30T22:18:59.532387Z    21 Prepare   UPDATE QueueJobsPending
            SET jobKey = ?,jobState = ?,queueName = ?,params = ?,tags = ?,maxExecutionTime = ?,maxReleases = ?,releasesCounter = ?,maxRetries = ?,retriesCounter = ?,executeAfterTimestamp = ?,createdAt = ?,updatedAt = ?
            WHERE id = ?
2024-11-30T22:18:59.532511Z    17 Close stmt    
2024-11-30T22:18:59.532562Z    21 Execute   UPDATE QueueJobsPending
            SET jobKey = 'SendCustomerAppointmentRescheduledEmail',jobState = 'Processing',queueName = 'Medium',params = '{\"orderId\":\"jNpAhJ9oOLqJkjv\"}',tags = '{\"orderId\":\"jNpAhJ9oOLqJkjv\",\"companyId\":\"87ZIKFuNgI14YSW\"}',maxExecutionTime = '30',maxReleases = '0',releasesCounter = '0',maxRetries = '3',retriesCounter = '0',executeAfterTimestamp = '1733005138',createdAt = '2024-11-30 22:18:58',updatedAt = '2024-11-30 22:18:59'
            WHERE id = 'fZCR4WbvNwxAb1Y'
2024-11-30T22:18:59.532801Z    17 Query COMMIT
2024-11-30T22:18:59.533188Z    15 Prepare   UPDATE QueueJobsPending
            SET jobKey = ?,jobState = ?,queueName = ?,params = ?,tags = ?,maxExecutionTime = ?,maxReleases = ?,releasesCounter = ?,maxRetries = ?,retriesCounter = ?,executeAfterTimestamp = ?,createdAt = ?,updatedAt = ?
            WHERE id = ?
2024-11-30T22:18:59.533412Z    15 Execute   UPDATE QueueJobsPending
            SET jobKey = 'SendCompanyUserAppointmentRescheduledEmail',jobState = 'Processing',queueName = 'Medium',params = '{\"orderId\":\"jNpAhJ9oOLqJkjv\"}',tags = '{\"orderId\":\"jNpAhJ9oOLqJkjv\",\"companyId\":\"87ZIKFuNgI14YSW\"}',maxExecutionTime = '30',maxReleases = '0',releasesCounter = '0',maxRetries = '3',retriesCounter = '0',executeAfterTimestamp = '1733005138',createdAt = '2024-11-30 22:18:58',updatedAt = '2024-11-30 22:18:59'
            WHERE id = 'K4cr7SCAaIQDsxl'
2024-11-30T22:18:59.558046Z    21 Close stmt    
2024-11-30T22:18:59.558112Z    21 Query COMMIT
2024-11-30T22:18:59.562778Z    15 Close stmt    
2024-11-30T22:18:59.562845Z    15 Query ROLLBACK
2024-11-30T22:18:59.564264Z    15 Quit  
2024-11-30T22:18:59.565126Z    14 Query START TRANSACTION
2024-11-30T22:18:59.565645Z    14 Prepare   SELECT QueueJobsPending.id AS QueueJobsPending_id,QueueJobsPending.jobKey AS QueueJobsPending_jobKey,QueueJobsPending.jobState AS QueueJobsPending_jobState,QueueJobsPending.queueName AS QueueJobsPending_queueName,QueueJobsPending.params AS QueueJobsPending_params,QueueJobsPending.tags AS QueueJobsPending_tags,QueueJobsPending.maxExecutionTime AS QueueJobsPending_maxExecutionTime,QueueJobsPending.maxReleases AS QueueJobsPending_maxReleases,QueueJobsPending.releasesCounter AS QueueJobsPending_releasesCounter,QueueJobsPending.maxRetries AS QueueJobsPending_maxRetries,QueueJobsPending.retriesCounter AS QueueJobsPending_retriesCounter,QueueJobsPending.executeAfterTimestamp AS QueueJobsPending_executeAfterTimestamp,QueueJobsPending.createdAt AS QueueJobsPending_createdAt,QueueJobsPending.updatedAt AS QueueJobsPending_updatedAt
                FROM QueueJobsPending
                WHERE
                    jobState = 'Pending'
                    AND executeAfterTimestamp <= '1733005139'
                    AND queueName IN ('low','high','medium')
                ORDER BY FIELD(queueName, 'low','high','medium'), sequence ASC
                LIMIT 1
                FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
2024-11-30T22:18:59.565774Z    14 Execute   SELECT QueueJobsPending.id AS QueueJobsPending_id,QueueJobsPending.jobKey AS QueueJobsPending_jobKey,QueueJobsPending.jobState AS QueueJobsPending_jobState,QueueJobsPending.queueName AS QueueJobsPending_queueName,QueueJobsPending.params AS QueueJobsPending_params,QueueJobsPending.tags AS QueueJobsPending_tags,QueueJobsPending.maxExecutionTime AS QueueJobsPending_maxExecutionTime,QueueJobsPending.maxReleases AS QueueJobsPending_maxReleases,QueueJobsPending.releasesCounter AS QueueJobsPending_releasesCounter,QueueJobsPending.maxRetries AS QueueJobsPending_maxRetries,QueueJobsPending.retriesCounter AS QueueJobsPending_retriesCounter,QueueJobsPending.executeAfterTimestamp AS QueueJobsPending_executeAfterTimestamp,QueueJobsPending.createdAt AS QueueJobsPending_createdAt,QueueJobsPending.updatedAt AS QueueJobsPending_updatedAt
                FROM QueueJobsPending
                WHERE
                    jobState = 'Pending'
                    AND executeAfterTimestamp <= '1733005139'
                    AND queueName IN ('low','high','medium')
                ORDER BY FIELD(queueName, 'low','high','medium'), sequence ASC
                LIMIT 1
                FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
2024-11-30T22:18:59.566372Z    14 Close stmt    
2024-11-30T22:18:59.566939Z    14 Prepare   UPDATE QueueJobsPending
            SET jobKey = ?,jobState = ?,queueName = ?,params = ?,tags = ?,maxExecutionTime = ?,maxReleases = ?,releasesCounter = ?,maxRetries = ?,retriesCounter = ?,executeAfterTimestamp = ?,createdAt = ?,updatedAt = ?
            WHERE id = ?
2024-11-30T22:18:59.567002Z    14 Execute   UPDATE QueueJobsPending
            SET jobKey = 'SendCompanyUserAppointmentRescheduledEmail',jobState = 'Processing',queueName = 'Medium',params = '{\"orderId\":\"jNpAhJ9oOLqJkjv\"}',tags = '{\"orderId\":\"jNpAhJ9oOLqJkjv\",\"companyId\":\"87ZIKFuNgI14YSW\"}',maxExecutionTime = '30',maxReleases = '0',releasesCounter = '0',maxRetries = '3',retriesCounter = '0',executeAfterTimestamp = '1733005138',createdAt = '2024-11-30 22:18:58',updatedAt = '2024-11-30 22:18:59'
            WHERE id = 'K4cr7SCAaIQDsxl'
2024-11-30T22:18:59.567160Z    16 Query START TRANSACTION
2024-11-30T22:18:59.567560Z    14 Close stmt    
2024-11-30T22:18:59.567635Z    14 Query COMMIT
2024-11-30T22:18:59.568050Z    16 Prepare   SELECT QueueJobsPending.id AS QueueJobsPending_id,QueueJobsPending.jobKey AS QueueJobsPending_jobKey,QueueJobsPending.jobState AS QueueJobsPending_jobState,QueueJobsPending.queueName AS QueueJobsPending_queueName,QueueJobsPending.params AS QueueJobsPending_params,QueueJobsPending.tags AS QueueJobsPending_tags,QueueJobsPending.maxExecutionTime AS QueueJobsPending_maxExecutionTime,QueueJobsPending.maxReleases AS QueueJobsPending_maxReleases,QueueJobsPending.releasesCounter AS QueueJobsPending_releasesCounter,QueueJobsPending.maxRetries AS QueueJobsPending_maxRetries,QueueJobsPending.retriesCounter AS QueueJobsPending_retriesCounter,QueueJobsPending.executeAfterTimestamp AS QueueJobsPending_executeAfterTimestamp,QueueJobsPending.createdAt AS QueueJobsPending_createdAt,QueueJobsPending.updatedAt AS QueueJobsPending_updatedAt
                FROM QueueJobsPending
                WHERE
                    jobState = 'Pending'
                    AND executeAfterTimestamp <= '1733005139'
                    AND queueName IN ('low','high','medium')
                ORDER BY FIELD(queueName, 'low','high','medium'), sequence ASC
                LIMIT 1
                FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
2024-11-30T22:18:59.568133Z    16 Execute   SELECT QueueJobsPending.id AS QueueJobsPending_id,QueueJobsPending.jobKey AS QueueJobsPending_jobKey,QueueJobsPending.jobState AS QueueJobsPending_jobState,QueueJobsPending.queueName AS QueueJobsPending_queueName,QueueJobsPending.params AS QueueJobsPending_params,QueueJobsPending.tags AS QueueJobsPending_tags,QueueJobsPending.maxExecutionTime AS QueueJobsPending_maxExecutionTime,QueueJobsPending.maxReleases AS QueueJobsPending_maxReleases,QueueJobsPending.releasesCounter AS QueueJobsPending_releasesCounter,QueueJobsPending.maxRetries AS QueueJobsPending_maxRetries,QueueJobsPending.retriesCounter AS QueueJobsPending_retriesCounter,QueueJobsPending.executeAfterTimestamp AS QueueJobsPending_executeAfterTimestamp,QueueJobsPending.createdAt AS QueueJobsPending_createdAt,QueueJobsPending.updatedAt AS QueueJobsPending_updatedAt
                FROM QueueJobsPending
                WHERE
                    jobState = 'Pending'
                    AND executeAfterTimestamp <= '1733005139'
                    AND queueName IN ('low','high','medium')
                ORDER BY FIELD(queueName, 'low','high','medium'), sequence ASC
                LIMIT 1
                FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
2024-11-30T22:18:59.568530Z    16 Close stmt    
2024-11-30T22:18:59.568789Z    16 Query COMMIT
...

After doing some more research on the deadlock problem itself I found this stackoverflow thread, which the first answer seems to indicate there is potential issue when two different indexes are used to lock the same row, which could be the reason in my case? From what I understood, its like two connections are locking the same row but using different indexes, adn that's what causing the deadlock.
These are the outputs I get when running explain in the two queries


I tried to provide as much details as possible (but maybe I went too far )
Anyways, any help is much appreciated, thanks! 
UPDATE 1:
I tried running the same queries from the terminal to see if two session would retrieve the same row from QueueJobsPending and it does not, SKIP LOCKED works as expected, below is a screenshot (I ran the right side first).

UPDATE 2:
Could it be related to the locks that are put in place when my select query runs concurrently?
I know these are two very different examples, but my locks look quite a bit different then the ones in this page https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-1-using-skip-locked-and-nowait-to-handle-hot-rows/
All locks in the page above are placed against the primary id column, in my case, they are all placed against the index_jobState column. There is one against the primary key, but the lock type is weird.


a) is it innoDB? b) is autocommit disabled?

a) Yes, InnoDB.
b) Not sure how to check if autocommit is disabled/enabled by default , but it seems like it is enabled, because if I run SELECT @@autocommit; from phpMyAdmin I get 1.
Also, MySQL version is 8.2.0.

The docs say, it is important to make sure it is disabled before using any transactions. So a set autocommit=0 should be sufficent.

Let me give that a shot . Also can you point where in the docs this is mentioned?

"Need help (very detailed question)" In your title does not make sense, as you are asking a question, it is known that your need help. And being "very detailed" only helps in getting a quick answer. But seeing the first comment..... (it was not detailed enough!) , so again no reason to mention that!

I cannot find the statement that @MarkusZeller is making, after reading: 17.7.2.2 autocommit, Commit, and Rollback and this 15.3.1 START TRANSACTION, COMMIT, and ROLLBACK Statements

I tried adding set autocommit=0 but still got a deadlock .
Looking at the mysql logs again, for some reason it really seems like FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED is having no effect at all, since two workers are trying to set the same job as Processing, so they must be getting the same job ID after running the select statement even tho FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED should not allow it .

When doing "Note: I update the status to Processing", you should be aware that other processes only see this AFTER the COMMIT.

Good point, but other processed should not even retrieve that same row in the first place, right? Since I used FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED only one of the workers should have gotten access to a particular row from QueueJobsPending, am I correct? I wonder if I misunderstood or if I'm missing something .

I posted an update to the question, I tried running the same query from two shell sessions and I did not get the same row twice, so there is something extra going on when these same queries are executed from the code . The other thing that I noticed in the mysql logs that could maybe have something to do with this issue are these Prepare SELECT QueueJobsPending.id, Execute SELECT QueueJobsPending.id and Close stmt, I thought prepared statement was something done on the PHP side of things, but maybe not.

I think I found where the "set autocommit=0" from @MarkusZeller came from, its here https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-1-using-skip-locked-and-nowait-to-handle-hot-rows/ in the "Quick tip:" section.

I referred the notes on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Can you show the setProcessing method? Maybe there is another index used in the update statement which hits another index causing the deadlock.

@MarkusZeller: "Locking reads are only possible when autocommit is disabled (either by beginning transaction with START TRANSACTION or by setting autocommit to 0."   (Note)

@MarkusZeller all setProcessing() does it set the jobState property of the $job entity to Processing, no DB operations there, then $this->update($job) is what actually performs the DB operation, I will update the question with both ->setProcessing() and ->update() methods.

@MarkusZeller the code for fetching the next job and setting its state to Processing is all done inside a transaction, so I think I don't need the autocommit=0, right?

@Luuk Yes, if you trust the PHP mysql driver. I had once the issue that my begin statement was ignored and autocomitted until I manually disabled autocommitting by the set query. So I am going to have that query directly after connecting to never ever experience that again.

Looking at the update query, I am sure it may use another index. You filter by ID there, but the select has many more criteria (that matches not only the id index).

@MarkusZeller that's a good observation about the different indexes being used, but do they need to match exactly? Meaning the index used by the select query must be the same used by the update one? In my case the update query is only executed if the select query returns something, and FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED is supposed to ensure only a single session gets the lock for a given row, in which case the current session would be the one holding the lock, so it should be able to run the update query without the risk of running into a deadlock, does that makes sense?

As far as I understood the topic, it is locked until the transaction either commits or rollbacks, but the lock (when not shared for reading) is also locked for any other connection. You could try to use the same query for the update as you do with select. As you have already included a sequence in order it should not conflict. I can not proof, but just guess and hope my suggestion helps.


Replace the index index_jobState with these
 INDEX(jobState, executeAfterTimestamp, queueName,
       sequence, id)
 INDEX(jobState, queueName, executeAfterTimestamp,
       sequence, id)



Logic:  Having all the WHERE and ORDER BY and PRIMARY KEY columns in a single index (suitably arranged) may speed up the query, thereby helping speed up the query and decrease the number of locked rows.  This may help avoid deadlocks and other delays.

Elaborate on what this is and how it is set:
 id CHAR(15) BINARY UNIQUE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id)



Logic:  That may be part of the problem, especially since it seems to be some kind of random UUID.
Getting rid of id and changing sequence AUTO_INCREMENT to be the PRIMARY KEY may improve performance.
Declaring id as UNIQUE is redundant with PRIMARY KEY.  This may be leading to the battle of two indexes.  Even if you don't do my other suggestions, drop the UNIQUE declaration.

Try these two formulations:
 BEGIN:
     SELECT ...; -- without the SKIP LOCKED
     UPDATE ...;
 COMMIT; 

or, skip the SELECT by doing
 UPDATE QueueJobsPending
     SET    jobState = 'Processing',
            createdAt = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),
            updatedAt = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),
            [[ any other columns that need changing ]]
     WHERE  jobState = 'Pending'
       AND  executeAfterTimestamp <= 123456789
       AND  queueName IN ('High','Medium','Low')
     ORDER BY  FIELD(queueName, 'High','Medium','Low'),
               sequence ASC
     LIMIT  1;

(and keep autocommit=1 for that UPDATE.)

If this is coming from redis, then pass my comments on to them.



Wow, great call on the redundant UNIQUE constraint on my primary keys, it really is redundant, not sure what I was thinking . Thanks!

Is the BEGIN SELECT... UPDATE... COMMIT guaranteed to be atomic? Also would it update and return the updated item all at once? I'm skeptical of not using SKIP LOCKED .

I'm afraid the UPDATE SET won't work for me, otherwise I think I would need to make a second query to get item that was set as processing, but I wouldn't have its ID, right? So not sure how I could use that one in my case, appreciate the suggestion.

@IsaacSouza - If you also need to work with the various columns, I suggest BEGIN; SELECT ... FOR UPDATE ...; UPDATE ...; COMMIT;  But the UPDATE need specify only the things being changed.  The FOR UPDATE locks the row until COMMIT.
